# Error when initialize an array in VBScript without specify its size (Subscript out of range)

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I'm just trying to initialize an array in VBScript without specify its size and I'm getting the error: "Subscript out of range".

```
Option Explicit 
dim arr()
arr(0)=2
Call MsgBox("arr: " & arr(0)) 'It prints 2
```

When I just edit the 2nd line to `dim arr(1)` it works.

I wonder it is a bug. Or I'm missing something?

I'm newbie with VBScript

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by initializing an array without defining its size? As you've seen -- it isn't possible. What are you hoping to do? Perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: @JohnColeman, That's because I dont know how many elements will be inserted in this array. Sometimes it can be hundreds or thousands

Comment: In case you don't know the size upfront, use `ReDim Preserve` to size the array without losing the contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@PankajJaju already gave a good answer to your basic question.

If your intention is to have an array which can dynamically expand as needed, you might want to use an [array list](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_data_arraylist.php):

```
Option Explicit
dim arr

Set arr = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
arr.add 2

msgbox "arr: " & arr(0) 'it *does* print 2!
```

In addition to being able to expand dynamically, array lists also have a nice sort method. The link I gave above shows how to use them from VBScript.

(Also -- note that you can invoke subs without the keyword `Call` -- though if you do so with a sub as opposed to a function you need to drop parentheses around the arguments the way I did with `msgbox`).

Answer (score 2):

When you do `dim arr()` it means its without any size. So to use it, you first need to make sure that you specify a size while declaring like `dim arr(1)` or by using `ReDim arry(1)`.

**Basics**

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/vbscript_variables.asp

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7zd6etz(v=vs.84).aspx